# »von ihnen« vs. »davon« und »von denen« vs. »wovon«

Tags: relative-clause, pronominal-adverb

Sind diese Sätze richtig? Gibt es einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung?

1. > a) Das sind die Brillen. Ich habe dir von ihnen erzählt.
   >
   > b) Das sind die Brillen. Ich habe dir davon erzählt.
2. > a) Das sind die Brillen, von denen ich dir erzählt habe.
   >
   > b) Das sind die Brillen, wovon ich dir erzählt habe.

Comment: To everybody: Please stay civil in the comments and assume good intentions. @maicart: Please [edit] your question to elaborate what you found so far on your research. It helps you get better answers, because it tells us where we need to start explaining and where the problems are (remember that native speakers may not see them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Wovon" wird verwendet, wenn man von einer Sache redet. Da die Brillen im Plural sind, ist a) in beiden Fällen korrekt.

1 b) ist aus meiner Sicht noch akzeptabel. Man kann den Satz als "Ich habe dir von den Brillen erzählt", aber auch als "Ich habe dir von der Sache mit den Brillen erzählt" lesen,  was letztlich in der Bedeutung keinen großen Unterschied macht, aber die 2. Variante passt besser zu "wovon".

2 b) klingt für mich wegen der Abweichung im Numerus schief, aber hier mögen die Ansichten auseinandergehen.

Bei Thomas Mann lese ich:

> Von einem kleinen Gemüseladen kaufte er einige Früchte, Erdbeeren, überreife und weiche Ware, und aß im Gehen davon.
>   (*Der Tod in Venedig*, 5.Kapitel)

was allerdings nicht unbedingt als Gegenbeispiel gegen meine Einschätzung angeführt werden kann, da man "davon" auf "Ware" (Singular) beziehen kann anstatt auf "Früchte".

(Dass im Zitat "davon" steht und nicht "wovon", macht aus meiner Sicht keinen entscheidenden Unterschied)